# How do I split a string of bullet points (with titles and body content) up into a multi dimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

I have some text that I have extracted from a PDF document that has a list of bullet points with content in them such as the following:

> 3 BILL REFERRED TO MAIL COMMITTEE
>   Mr Fitzgibbon (Chief Government Whip), by leave, moved—That the Tax Laws Amendment (2011 
>   Measures No. 7) Bill 2011 be referred to the Main Committee for further consideration. 
>   Question—put and passed.
>    4 CORPORATIONS AMENDMENT (FUTURE OF FINANCIAL ADVICE) BILL 2011
>   Mr Shorten (Minister for Financial Services and Superannuation), pursuant to notice, presented a Bill 
>   for an Act to amend the law in relation to financial advice, and for related purposes. 
>   Document 
>   Mr Shorten presented an explanatory memorandum to the bill. 
>   Bill read a first time. 
>   Mr Shorten moved—That the bill be now read a second time. 
>   Debate adjourned (Mr Randall), and the resumption of the debate made an order of the day for the next 
>   sitting.
>    5 TAX LAWS AMENDMENT (2011 MEASURES NO. 8) BILL 2011
>   Mr Shorten (Minister for Financial Services and Superannuation) presented a Bill for an Act to amend 
>   the law relating to taxation, and for related purposes. 
>   Document

I need to split these up so that I have each bullet point in something like this:

> [0,0] = Title
>   [0,1] = Body
>   [1,0] = Title
>   [1,1] = Body

**I have modified the example to include some real world content.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am using the .NET framework C#.

Comment: Where are `2011` and `2012` coming from?

Comment: Fixed now. Was not meant to be there.

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or something you'll need to do over and over?

Comment: This is something that will be done over and over where the title and content will be different. It will be a task that will run daily when new PDF's arrive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = input
    .Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .GroupAdjacent((g, x) => !char.IsDigit(x[0]))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Title = g.First().Trim(),
        Body = string.Join(" ", g.Skip(1).Select(x => x.Trim()))
    })
    .ToArray();
```

*Example:*

```
string input = @"3 BILL REFERRED TO MAIL COMMITTEE
Mr Fitzgibbon (Chief Government Whip), by leave, moved—That the
Tax Laws Amendment (2011 Measures No. 7) Bill 2011 be referred
to the Main Committee for further consideration. Question—put
and passed.

4 CORPORATIONS AMENDMENT (FUTURE OF FINANCIAL ADVICE) BILL 2011
Mr Shorten (Minister for Financial Services and Superannuation),
pursuant to notice, presented a Bill for an Act to amend the law
in relation to financial advice,and for related purposes. Mr
Shorten presented an explanatory memorandum to the bill. Bill
read a first time. Mr Shorten moved—That the bill be now read
a second time. Debate adjourned (Mr Randall), and the resumption
of the debate made an order of the day for the next sitting.

5 TAX LAWS AMENDMENT (2011 MEASURES NO. 8) BILL 2011
Mr Shorten (Minister for Financial Services and Superannuation)
presented a Bill for an Act to amend the law relating to
taxation, and for related purposes.";
```

*Output:*

```
result[0] == { Title = "3 BILL REFERRED ...", Body = "Mr Fitzgibbon ..." }
result[1] == { Title = "4 CORPORATIONS ...",  Body = "Mr Shorten ..." }
result[2] == { Title = "5 TAX LAWS ...",      Body = "Mr Shorten ..." }
```

*Extension Method:*

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> adjacent)
{
    var g = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (g.Count != 0 && !adjacent(g, x))
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<T>();
        }
        g.Add(x);
    }
    yield return g;
}
```

Comment: That works for the sample that I provided. Thank you. I think I have to modify the question and provide a different example because it does not work on my text from my PDF. My fault for not providing a better example

Comment: Perfect. This has really helped. Love the extension method. Just need to do a small adjustment to tailor to the way the content comes out. Thanks heaps!